# "the thing someone did was do something" or "the thing someone did was doing something"?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, past-continuous

Here is what I have found in [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/L-K19rVDxoM) at 13 minute and 4 second, and it really confused me.

> Whereas if you are an american arguably the most important thing the leader of this era ever did was **raise** George W Bush.

The reason I am baffled is that the parts of the sentence don't seem to me to agree. Would it be more grammatical if said:

> ...ever did was **raising**...

or

> ...ever did was **raised**...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement in this pattern is a clause headed by a non-finite form of the verb, thus **(to) raise** or **raising**.

> The best thing we can do is to lower the tax on bubble gum.
>
> The best thing  we can do is lower the tax on bubble gum.
>
> The best thing  we can do is lowering the tax on bubble gum.
>
> The best thing any leader of this era ever did was lower the tax on bubble gum.

Stylistically the *ing*-form is considered a little clunky there, and the marked infinitive is regarded by many as better here than the unmarked. But all three forms are used by native speakers.

Alternatively a clause with a finite verb with subject repeated:

> The best thing we can do is *we lower  the tax on bubble gum*.
>
> The best thing he can do is *he lowers the tax on bubble gum*.

This form is colloquial.